# Mac OS Lion and Sandboxing

Tags: cocoa, macos, sandbox, osx-lion

I am developping a file manager app for Mac OS and I was wondering what can be the impact of the new sandboxing function of Mac OS.

Any experience?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to distribute your app through the Mac app store?

Comment: yes I am planning to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandboxing your application is currently optional.  You have to put code in your application to sandbox it by using the sandbox_init() function.

**References**:
http://techjournal.318.com/security/a-brief-introduction-to-mac-os-x-sandbox-technology/
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sandbox_init.3.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the old articles you link to do not apply to apps distributed through the Lion App Store.

Answer (score 7):

The Matthieu's answer is obsolete. With Lion, you have to refer to [Code Signing And Application Sandboxing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH1-SW1).

Also read this question: [Howto "sandbox" my Lion application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834179/howto-sandbox-my-lion-application)