# Howto "sandbox" my Lion application?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, sandbox, osx-lion

Apple has decreed that all applications submitted to the Mac App Store must be sandboxed, starting in November.

Ok, but how can I "sandbox" my app?

I found the official Apple's guide [Code Signing And Application Sandboxing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929).

This document lists the following steps:

1) "Enable sandboxing for your application." Ok, easy: I have to open Xcode 4, select the project, select the target, go to the Summary tab and check:

- "Enable Entitlements"
- "Enable App Sandboxing"
- ...and every single entitlement I'm interested in.

2) Then: "Once you have created a basic entitlements profile, you should sign your application". In short, the guide says to run the command "codesign" on the .app.

But on which .app?

I have to do this every time I compile?

Xcode does not do that in automatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you turn on sandboxing for your app, Xcode will automatically sign the built product using the `codesign` tool.

You'd only need to run the `codesign` tool manually if you wanted to customise the code signing behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I also thought that Xcode does automatically sign the build using codesign. However, when I run my app and I open Activity Monitor, I see No on the column Sandbox. Is that correct? There is a way to better understand what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: It should "just work". Do you have a code signing developer certificate installed in your keychain? Is Xcode producing any warnings during the build process? Have you tried doing a "Clean" on your project?

Comment: You are right! My problem was due to the fact that when I run the app, it is used the Debug build configuration. And in my case the Code Signing Identity for Debug is "Don't code sign". Thank you!